# Shared JS/TS modules between projects in StackBlitz

Tags: javascript, typescript, stackblitz

I'm a newbie in StackBlitz, I have only a few projects but I already have some utility functions as modules which I want to use in all projects.

Is there a way to share JS/TS/... modules between projects in StackBlitz? 
I don't mean of course Copy-Paste as a solution here ;).